# Managing objects - creating/accessing/storing from a central location

Tags: c#

I am working on a text-based game in WPF using MVVM. I am hoping to get some advice regarding managing created objects in my project. I would like to store and access my created objects in/from a central location. There are several different types of objects that I need to manage and I currently have everything relevant contained in a singleton class, which I have named `DataManager`, for easy access. When applicable, I'm storing, exposing, and populating `ObservableCollection<MyObject>`s in DataManager. From there I create properties in my ViewModels that get the required object(s) from DataManager.

So far this hasn't caused any problems, but I would like to get some input before I progress too far to avoid having to rewrite my code (again). Would it be worth looking into a database for a project like this? If not, can anybody provide any feedback or suggestions on how to do this better or more properly? Like I said, I would just like to know the 'correct' way to store and access created objects or collections of objects from a location that is globally accessible.

I would certainly appreciate any advice you could give me on this issue and I would be open to any suggestions. I would like to learn how to do this right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO, what you're doing is OK.

Regarding the DB question, a DB is to store data in a persistent manner, not in a temporary manner. That means that if you plan to "save" and "load" lots of data in your game, then a DB should be appropiate, otherwise your approach seems OK to me.

Comment: also maybe some kind of `store` (DB, DB in file like sqlite, just plain text or xml file, or anything else) will be needed to keep saves (quicksaves of game state against app crashes or progress saves). the complexity of mentioned by HighCore "saves" and "loads" will dictate the complexity of "storing".